# How upload csv file to SharePoint via NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi, sharepoint-online, data-ingestion

I want to upload a csv file in SharePoint via NiFi, is it possible? I can't find a processor that allows to ingest a csv file in SharePointe via NiFi, thank you for your help

I tried to search for processor PutSharePointList or PutSharePointOnline in https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/nifi/ but I can't find it

Comment: You could try achieving the same using the `InvokeHTTP` processor and upload the file using the Sharepoint Rest API. You can find some details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/upload-a-file-by-using-the-rest-api-and-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no processor to connect directly to SharePoint but you can use REST API.
I had the same problem and i followed [this tutorial](https://itsfelipe.medium.com/tutorial-nifi-upload-files-to-sharepoint-api-with-template-ae9fa94b3a79) where they explain step by step, and i was able to upload my files to SharePoint using nifi, I hope it helps you too.